# sortable element inside a div can't be dropped on the HEADER of another div with sortable element INSIDE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

First, check this to understand what i'm talking about:
https://jsfiddle.net/3s1s7nn3/10/

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

If you take "ITEM 1" from the "LEFT red div" and move it on the "RIGHT red div", it will not drop it, it only work when you put the "ITEM" inside the item list of the div.

How can i allow my ITEMS to be dropped anywhere in the div and still have them placed in the itemlist ? (i don't want it to be placed elsewhere than the item list but i want to be able to drop it anywhere in the div, not just in the ITEM list).

Sorry if i'm not very clear..
Thanks

Comment: I made [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3s1s7nn3/11/), but it's a terrible kludge. Ashamed to post it as an answer.

Comment: thanks for posting it anyway, i guess this is the only solution i have to do the trick

Comment: Judging by your comment on the answer, this is no solution either. Like the answer, my fiddle also expands the list to fill the container. I'm afraid you'll have to create a lot of Javascript to detect things dropped on the container and then put them in the appropriate list.

Comment: see my other answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189918/sortable-element-inside-a-div-cant-be-dropped-on-the-header-of-another-div-with#comment50386122_31190184 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know, i have worked on a solution from zero, and i figured out !

```
SOLUTION :
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3s1s7nn3/33/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot drop them in the div because you are connecting it with the list `connectedSortable` and you cannot drop them outside the list.
If you want to add some space from the top and still be able to drop them into the list you should use `padding` not `margin`.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3zv4yvr3/) is a working example.

Comment: thanks for the answer, in fact i simplified the code on the jsfiddle, the real problem is the fact that i want to be able to drop an item outside the item list (on the parent div basically) but still have it inside it after the drop (because on my project, my item lists are inside collapsed accordions, so i need to be able to drop an item on the header of the accordion..). but as you said, it's not possible :/

Comment: i found another way to handle this by opening the accordion when i'm dragging something over it : http://jsfiddle.net/CK9uL/

Comment: I'm so glad you found a way :)